# JavaScript preloader for Website, its not working IE,

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have created one JavaScript preloader for our Website but it is not working IE, how to fix this issue please let me if anyone knows about this.

```
<div class="preloader-wrapper">
    <div class="preloader">
        <img src="images/Preloader.gif" alt="" >
    </div>
</div> 


//javaScript
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var Body = $('body');
    Body.addClass('preloader-site');
    });
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.preloader-wrapper').fadeOut();
    $('body').removeClass('preloader-site');
});
```

Comment: What isn't working? Did nothing show up? Did the class not change? Errors in the console?

Comment: no, everything is fine but still it's not working in IE only

Comment: I tested with your code and the results are the same in IE and in other browsers. The picture will fadeout in browsers. What do you mean not working? Can the gif show normally in IE without the javascript? I can't reproduce issue with your above code. Please check if the issue related with other code and please provide [a reproducibe sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes now its work, in my code I had some mistake

Comment: Great! You could also put your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer.  It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @YuZhou this is my another question link please can you help me what need to do exactly:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884023/how-to-make-preloader-show-only-once

Answer (score 0):

Add a closing tag for image.

`<img ... />`

Answer (score 0):

I made these changes in my code now it's working all browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
var Body = $('body');
Body.addClass('preloader-site');
});
function preloadeSite(){

$('.preloader-wrapper').fadeOut();
$('body').removeClass('preloader-site');
}

window.addEventListener('load', preloadeSite);
```